# can i start an export via admin api in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

I created an profile for exporting products.

Is there a way to start the export with the api ?
And then downloading that .csv file with the api ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way. See the [`ImportExportActionController`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b9710d639753cf42718987ab83467ac52a1170dd/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Controller/ImportExportActionController.php).

Using your admin api credentials you can request the following endpoints in that order with the respective payloads:

```
POST /api/_action/import-export/prepare
{
    "profileId": "...",
    "expireDate": "2022-12-12 12:00:00"
}
```

`profileId` would be the id of the profile you want to use for exporting. `expireDate` is a date after which the export would be deemed expired and ready to be deleted. Set it sometime into the future. There's also the parameter `file` which would contain the file you're trying to import, but since you want to export you just omit it.

This endpoint will return a `logId` you'll need in the next step.

```
POST /api/_action/import-export/process
{
    "logId": "..."
}
```

Requesting this endpoint with the `logId` you got from the prior request will actually start the export/import.

The import/export will run in the message queue so you'll have to wait for the process to finish at this point.

```
POST /api/search/import-export-log
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "equals",
            "field": "id",
            "value": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Use the search endpoint for the `import_export_log` entities with the `logId` you received previously as a filter. You can do so to check the `state` of the process so you can proceed once it is finished. For the download you'll also need the `fileId` from this record.

```
POST /api/_action/import-export/file/prepare-download/{fileId}
```

Use the `fileId` you received previously to request this endpoint. It will return an `accessToken` you'll need for the final request.

```
GET /api/_action/import-export/file/download?accessToken=...&fileId=...
```

Using both the `fileId` and the `accessToken` from earlier, request this endpoint which should yield a download stream of the exported file.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. Is there any documentation about this? i haven't found any